# How to malloc for different char pointers

Tags: c, pointers, char, malloc

I have a struct like this

```
struct Patient {
    char* name;
    char* address;
    char* socialSecurityNumber;
    char* typeOfExamination;
    bool isExpress;
}
```

And I have to fill a dynamic array of this struct from a txt file like this:
(delimiter: ";")

```
Andrew;Address street first;123;pulmonary;1
Matthew;Address street second;456;COVID;0
Lisa;Address street third;789;rectum;0
```

After opening the file and reading the file:

```
while (fgets(line, 255, (FILE*) fPtr)) {
        char *p = strtok (line, ";");
        patients[i].name=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char*));
        strcpy(patients[i].name, p);

        p = strtok (NULL, ";");
        patients[i].address=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char*));
        strcpy(patients[i].address, p);
        
        ...

        i++;
    }
```

After the second malloc/strcpy I get a sysmalloc: Assertion failed error

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Or `parients[i].name=strdup(p);` if `strdup()` is supported in your system.

Answer (score 0):

`patients[i].name=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char*));` allocates enough space for a single character pointer, about 4 to 8 bytes. You need to allocate enough space for each character, plus a null byte at the end.

```
patients[i].name = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(p)+1));
```

That will work, but we can slim it down. [There's no need to cast `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc). Normally we also multiply the length by `sizeof` the type, but `sizeof(char)` is always 1, so it can be omitted.

```
patients[i].name = malloc(strlen(p)+1);
```

You can use [`strdup`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strdup.html) to do the same thing, but that's a POSIX function not always available. It's often worthwhile to write your own.

```
patients[i].name = strdup(p);
```